# Can't build Ardusim

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build Ardusim for use on my turtlebot.  ROS Electric, Ubuntu 10.04 and I issued these commands:

alan@alan-desktop:~$ cd ~/ros_workspace

alan@alan-desktop:~/ros_workspace$ svn checkout http://isr-uc-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/lse_arduino/trunk/ardusim

alan@alan-desktop:~/ros_workspace$ cd ardusim
alan@alan-desktop:~/ros_workspace/ardusim$ rosmake

But, I don't think it found everything:

Failed to find stack for package [lse_sensor_msgs]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [lse_sensor_msgs]:Cannot locate installation of package lse_sensor_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [lse_sensor_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/alan/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]
Failed to find stack for package [cereal_port]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [cereal_port]:Cannot locate installation of package cereal_port: [rospack] couldn't find package [cereal_port]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/alan/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]

So what is the proper way to get and build Ardusim?

Thanks,

Alan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45152/can%27t-build-ardusim/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if there is an automatic way to install the dependencies, but you can find the missing stacks at:

lse_sensor_msgs -> http://isr-uc-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/lse_messages/trunk/

cereal_port -> http://isr-uc-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/serial_communication/trunk/

If you installed ROS from source you can use the tools [roslocate](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslocate) and [rosinstall](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall) to do it.

Maybe some *installation* guru can give you a better approach or take a look at this answer: [installing ros packages from source](http://answers.ros.org/question/10581/installing-ros-packages-from-source/?answer=15654#post-id-15654).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0